# Python comparing two files partially

Tags: python

I have the two input file:

Input 1:

okay    sentence
two runway
three   runway
right   runway
one pathway

four    pathway
zero    pathway

Input 2 :

okay    sentence
two runway
three   runway
right   runway
zero    pathway

one pathway
four    pathway

I have used the following code:

```
def diff(a, b):
y = []
for x in a:
    if x not in b:
        y.append(x)
    else:
        b.remove(x)
return y

with open('output_ref.txt', 'r') as file1:
   with open('output_ref1.txt', 'r') as file2:
    same = diff(list(file1), list(file2))
    print same
    print "\n"

if '\n' in same:
  same.remove('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as FO:
  for line in same:
    FO.write(line)
```

And the expected output is :

one pathway

zero    pathway

But the output I am getting an empty output for this. The problem is I don't know how to store the content from the files to the list partially ,then compare and finally read it back from there. Can someone help me in this regard ??

Comment: what lines do you want from the file?

Comment: In the first part (first five line), 'one pathway' is missing in the second file's first half. And in the second part 'zero pathway' is missing. So these two lines are the expected output from the file.. Can u help me in getting this...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you just want to have the common text lines in both files, sets would provide a good way. Something like this:

```
content1 = set(open("file1", "r"))
content2 = set(open("file2", "r"))
diff_items = content1.difference(content2)
```

UPDATE: But is it so that the question is about difference in the same sense as the `diff` utility? I.e. the order is important (looks like that with the examples).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I dont want to use sets, rather I need to store the first half of the file partially and compare with the other file's first half, and do it in an iterative manner. Can you help me in this??

Answer (score 0):

Use  [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

```
with open('output_ref.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('output_ref1.txt', 'r') as file2:
        f1 = [x.strip() for x in file1] # get all lines and strip whitespace
        f2 = [x.strip() for x in file2]
        five_f1 = f1[0:5] # first five lines
        two_f1 = f1[5:] # rest of lines
        five_f2 = f2[0:5]
        two_f2 = f2[5:]
        s1 = set(five_f1)  # make sets to compare
        s2 = set(two_f1)
        s1 = s1.difference(five_f2) # in a but not b
        s2 = s2.difference(two_f2) 
        same = s1.union(s2)  


with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as FO:
    for line in same:
        FO.write(line+"\n") # add new line to write each word on separate line
```

Without sets using your own method:

```
with open('output_ref.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('output_ref1.txt', 'r') as file2:
        f1 = [x.strip() for x in file1]
        f2 = [x.strip() for x in file2]
        five_f1 = f1[0:5]
        two_f1 = f1[5:]
        five_f2 = f2[0:5]
        two_f2 = f2[5:]
        same = diff(five_f1,five_f2) + diff(two_f1,two_f2)
        print same
['one pathway', 'zero pathway']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I dont want to use sets, rather I need to store the first half of the file partially and compare with the other file's first half, and do it in an iterative manner. Can you help me in this??

Comment: Your output does not  make sense, what your function is doing is adding items to y that are in a but not in b, which is exactly what s.difference is doing, reword your question to show exactly how you expect your output